# how to let Hibernate to generate "is null" instead of bining column value to null

Tags: hibernate

Is there a way to let hibernate to generate sql query by using "is null" in additional to binding value to null? I am using DB2, I explained detail in following:

in my project, I used following persistent classes to map to DB tables (I used ElementCollection to map a collection of B instances in A instance):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implement Serializable {
   @Id
   @Colum(name = "A_A")
   private a_A;

   @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(name = "B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_A", nullable = false))
   @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   private Set<B> A_Bs = new HashSet<B>();;
   ....
}

@Embeddable
@Table(name = "B")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class B implements Serializable {
   @Column(name B_C)
   private String C;

   @Column(name B_D)
   private String D;

.....
}
```

when I try to update an entity instance of A, I can see the following sqls Hibernate generated by itself (since there is no id definition in B, it makes sense in general cases just to blindly update the collection anyway):

```
delete from B where B_A=? and B_C=? and B_D=? 
insert into B (B_A, B_C, B_D) values (?, ?, ?)
```

the problem is B_C and B_D is nullable, and B_D is a foreign key of another table(object).

So if the original value of B_C or B_D is null, the delete sql will become as:

```
delete from B where B_A=<somevalue> and B_C=null and B_D=null
```

in DB2, if you have "=null", DB2 not delete any rows, end up the second insert into query will fail. but in my application, I have to put null as value to B_C or B_D, so I would like hibernate generate querys like this:

```
delete from B where B_A=? and (B_C is null or B_C=?) and (B_D is null or B_D=?)
```

is there a way to do this?

Pls help. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you normalize your schema, make B an entity of its own, put a surrogate primary key in B, and make a OneToMany relationship between A and B?

This would be much more efficient (no need to delete all and reinsert each time the collection is updated) and you wouldn't have these problems anymore.

Comment: Hi JB, thanks for the reply. I personally have no objection to use onetomany, there are only 2 concerns:

Comment: 1. since Hibernate support ElementCollection, then it should generate the right sql for me, I was thinking I must miss the trick to do this.

Comment: 2. if I use unidirectional OneToMany mapping, all the examples I got on the net are using a mapping table, but in our db, we only have A and B tables, we don't have mapping table A_B. Is this ok? if you can give me a simple example, that will be great. thanks again.

Comment: You may have a unidirectional OneToMany with a foreign key in B pointing to A. Just use the OneToMany annotation with a JoinColumn annotation, as described here : http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#d0e1272

Comment: thanks. if you can answer my first concern, or confirm it's unresolvable (no trick), I will accept your answer. :)